# C++ code not running in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, codeblocks

I bought 'C++ For Dummies' around a week ago, and I'm trying to make a hello world program in Visual Studio, however the code doesn't work, it just says there are errors... The exact same code works fine in CodeBlocks, and I've searched Google for ages for an answer but there doesn't seem to be any :/ It's really confusing, it's almost like C++ is a completely different language to the one used in Code Blocks :/

I've checked that I'm definitely using C++, and I've tried Win32 Console and CLR Console, neither seem to be working. Would somebody be able to help? :/

Code:

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 

int main() 
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0; 
}
```

Error:

> Unable to start program *'location of program'*

Comment: What is the code? And what are the errors? Without those how can we possibly help?

Comment: You'd have to post some of the code you've written and error messages you've gotten in order to get an answer that could address any specifics.

Comment: Code: #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}

Comment: Error message: Unable to start program '*location of program*'

Comment: Does this solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013309/visual-studio-debugger-error-unable-to-start-program-specified-file-cannot-be-f

Comment: @Jessward25: That is not the error message. The error message(s) are found in the Visual Studio output window.

Comment: Does the Win32 Console project wizard turn on precompiled headers by default? Although in that case you would have had compiler errors for the missing `#include "stdafx.h"`

Answer (score 0):

This error can appear for a number of reasons.

1. If you have anti-virus installed, it *may* attempt to block any created .exe files (made when you built and compiled your program). To test this, turn it off (temporarily), or add the location of your Visual Studio Project 
   `[your_drive]:\[you]\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects`
   to the "safe zone" or trusted location found in your anti-virus settings.
2. Try "repairing" your installation of Visual Studio, via control panel->programs->"change" visual studio and then select "repair".
3. Overly long project/solution/file names have also been documented to generate this error.