# VISUAL STUDIO can't find the file specified

Tags: visual-studio

I wrote this C code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()

{
    int a;
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("%d\n", a);
    getchar();
    return 10;
}
```

However I am getting this error shown in image.
What is the problem here ?

EDIT1:
I have windows 7 x64 and running VS 15.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems there has been similar problem before this might be helpfull.

[Visual Studio debugger error: Unable to start program Specified file cannot be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013309/visual-studio-debugger-error-unable-to-start-program-specified-file-cannot-be-f)

Answer (score 0):

Go to the specific file location from the error open the program from there. Build it first then try to debug it again.