# Linphone Desktop on windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, linphone

When I build the latest update of `linphone-desktop` project on windows 10,
It builds in the VS2017 without any issues, but after that i get the error message:

`unable to start program. build\RelWithDebInfo\ALL_BUILD the system can not find the file specified.`

and when I open the exe in output\bin myself, I get an error:

`Linphone will crash. Unable to open main window`

What am I doing wrong? I tried to build in Debug and Release mode too, but no success.

Comment: Probably a bug with that app; contact them.

Comment: I have opened an issue on it's repository, But they don't care about issues that much... @MichaelChourdakis

Comment: Have you followed [these steps](https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-desktop#specific-instructions-for-the-windows-platform) exactly? Moreover I think you are experiencing a similar issue as mentioned in [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7013665/11613622). You need to run `cmake --build . --target ALL_BUILD` before running it from VS.

Comment: @brc-dd Yes. I have done that. BTW I will try again, step by step with a newer version of QT.

Comment: @SinaKH generally, linux-born so called "open source" projects do not bother if their code works or even compiles under windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to rebuild the project after updating to latest commit.

1. Updated QT from 5.9.8 to 5.12.1
2. Reset all the path environment variables after the QT update
3. Reinstalled the latest perl
4. Rebuilt the project step by step (I tried Release mode) and finally, it works :)

Comment: Hi , I've seen you had multiple problems while building linphone desktop on windows.
So you must be having a very good idea about the problems I'm having.
I'm having issues while bulding the project on my windows 10. I've installed everything as per their README but not able to build the project successfully. Currently the build is not showing any error but its not creating any binary or package as well.
I've explained everything in detail here in (this github issue)[https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-desktop/issues/423]. 
Can you please suggest something. Thanks