Why can't I build my cmake project in visual studio when it works from the command line?
I've made a cmake project that builds and runs fine from the command line. But, when there are more than a few simple errors, parsing the build output becomes incredibly tedious due to having to parse hundreds of lines of output.
I'd like to use Visual Studio 2019 so I can see my errors listed out, and use the degugger too. However, I cannot seem to build my project in VS Studio because one of my find_package calls receives the following errors:
CMake Error at C:\Users\E40056742\projects\JsonReader\CMakeLists.txt:16 (find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package "std_FUEL" that is
  compatible with requested version "2.6.1.1".

  The following configuration files were considered but not accepted:

    C:/FUEL/std_FUEL-2.6.1.1-Windows-x64-vs16.0/std_FUELConfig.cmake, version: 2.6.1.1

What I've tried
1. Command Line
On the command line, I'm using the bare bones cmake commands:

cd build
cmake ..
cmake --build . --config Debug

I can then navigate to and execute the resulting .exe with no issues.
2. Visual Studio 2019
I have tried the following both before and after deleting my build folder created from the command line steps above:

I open the folder containing my files.
It appears that VS2019 automatically tries to configure my cmake project. I immediately see the error mentioned in the output window.

If the output window is to be believed, this is the command that VS is trying to run:
CMake generation started for configuration: 'x64-Debug'. 1> Command line: "C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe" /c "%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\chcp.com 65001 >NUL && "C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\PROFESSIONAL\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\CMAKE\CMake\bin\cmake.exe"  -G "Ninja"  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING="Debug" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH="C:\Users\E40056742\projects\JsonReader\out\install\x64-Debug" -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH="C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe" -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH="C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe"  -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM="C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\PROFESSIONAL\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\CMAKE\Ninja\ninja.exe" "C:\Users\E40056742\projects\JsonReader" 2>&1"
Which is just a hot mess that I have no idea how to parse. I am a basic user that just wants to write code, and I have no idea how to debug such a large heap of characters into something meaningful that would lead me to a solution.
3. Open The solution made on the command line
Another another thing I've tried... I build from the command line with cmake then I try the option in VS2019 to open a solution. I point VS2019 at the .sln file generated by building with cmake on the command line.
That opens up my project, but I get a new error when I try to run it, this time a pop up rather than text in the output:
Unable to start program:
C:/Users/.../JsonReader/build/x64/Debug/ALL_BUILD/
Access Denied

My Question:
Can someone explain like I'm 5 how to use Visual Studio to build and debug my cmake project?

Concerning the error Unable to start program see that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013309/visual-studio-debugger-error-unable-to-start-program-specified-file-cannot-be-f

@Tsyvarev thank you. That allowed the third approach I listed to work.

Please, edit your question and remove errors which are solved somewhere else. Note, that on Stack Overflow we expect a question post to be focused on a single problem.

@Tsyvarev That portion of the question is listed under "What I've Tried". It is not a statement of the problem. It is a path I took to troubleshoot the problem. I will leave it. Thank you for your time.

Not sure why do you treat the section "What have I tried" as a way for post something which is otherwise bad. Such part of a question is expected to describe a fair attempt, which takes into account all information you have been able to find. BTW, I find your "initial" question perfectly valid, even if will be followed with "I am aware that I may configure the project in the command line and open it in the Visual Studio, but I expect it to work with Visual Studio directly".

When you configure the project in the command line, which configuration file is listed under Found std_FUEL: line? Is it the same as the config file which is not accepted in the configuration under Visual Studio?
